# ASP MVC DropDownList has extra value ( the integer id )

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I end up with three values in my DropDown... Two expected values and an additional value that is the primary key of the selecteditem, ie. "2"
How do I get rid of the "2", and still select the appropriate item?

[image]

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ComicBookId, ComicNet.Models.ComicBook.GetValues(), Model.ComicBookId.ToString(), new { @id = "ComicBookId" })


 public partial class ComicBook
    {
        public static SelectList GetValues()
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {

                SelectList selectList = new SelectList(db.ComicBooks.ToList(), "ComicBookId", "Name");

                return selectList; 

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the third parameter as it is setting the `optionLabel`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ComicBookId, ComicNet.Models.ComicBook.GetValues(), new { @id = "ComicBookId" })
```

This is the overload that you're using: [SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor Method (HtmlHelper, Expression>, IEnumerable, String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String,System.Object%29)

Here's the one you want: [SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor Method (HtmlHelper, Expression>, IEnumerable, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.Object%29)